# <li> in one line without wrapping

Tags: css

This is my code:

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

If I resize my browser window, the `<li>` start wrapping. But they should stay in one line. I took a look at a lot of other questions in this forum about similar issues, but I was not able to find the solution.

Comment: I think you need to add a media query for the smaller browser window size

Comment: Remove the `float: left;`. It is unnecessary since your items are `inline-block`. Float will prevent `white-space: nowrap` from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ul{ display:flex; flex-wrap: no-wrap}
```

Comment: no need to mention flex-direction: row; by default the direction is row